# Sql Server Reporting Service without Full SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am going to use SSRS to generate report for my website.

Scenario:

I have 2 servers, Application server & Database Server.
I want to have reports(.rdl files) sitting on Application server(IIS) accessing data on SQL server(Database Server)

In order to fulfil these requirement I require to install SQL server 2k5 on my Application server just for having SQL server reporting service. So I am just waisting one of licence of SQL server by installing that on Application server.

Is anyone having any idea how to install only reporting service with SQL server 2k5??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have Reporting Services on your Application server, you would have to use a SQL license. You can install just the Reporting Services section of SQL Server, but it is still technically part of the SQL Server application and requires a license for use on that processor(s).
If that is a huge issue, then I would have to recommend keeping the Reporting Services section installed with the rest of the database installation on your Data server.

http://www.microsoft.com/sql/prodinfo/previousversions/rs/howtolicensers.mspx

*The server components of SQL Server 2000 Reporting Services include the Report Server and the Report Server Database. The Report Server processes and renders reports, and handles scheduled events and report delivery. The Report Server Database stores report definitions, report metadata, subscription information, and so on. Each Report Server requires either a local or remote connection to a Report Server Database. **To use any of these components, each computer on which the Report Server and the Report Server Database are installed must have a valid SQL Server 2000 license.***

Comment: your answer is for 2000 but the question is 2005, and iirc 2005 allows for SSRS in the express version.  Also, would certain people stop flagging questions because they are incorrect?  Mods are like janitors.  You don't grab them when the teacher says something wrong. You grab them when Jimmy hurls in band class.

Answer (score 1):

You could install SQL Server Express on the application server.
It's free, and [there's an edition which comes with Reporting Services](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/InstallOptions.aspx).
In comparison with the "real" editions, SQL Server Express Edition is limited concerning how much CPU and RAM it can use, but it will probably be fast enough to run your reports.

Comment: The idea is good, except that ReportingServices express (&web) edition doesn't allow you to connect to a non-localhost database...

Answer (score 1):

blatantly incorrect. You do not need a SQL Server license to use SQL Server  Reporting Services, you can use SQL Server Express edition.  I've use SQL Server Express Edition in addition to linked servers-- to query stuff on -ANY- database server. And it works great.

SSRS is a great platform, I Just hate it when people run around saying that you NEED a license to use it.  I'll bet that guy works for Oracle corp!

Comment: I am not quite sure you are correct. You can get SSRS to work the way you say. But I believe if you read the hidden details of the MS licensing documentations they "DO" require that you have a Sql Server license. So what your saying you can do technically but if you do that in a prod environment your violating MS licensing, not that your likely to get caught.

Comment: Licensing agreement doesn't say anywhere that you can't use linked servers.

Comment: But using linked servers ain't that simple. You need to mirror every used stored-procedure, view & table with a local copy.

Comment: So? As oppopsed to spending $100k on an Enterprise License for a single socket? SSRS with Express Edition works just PERFECTLY, it's all that MOST PEOPLE need.

Answer (score 0):

You do have an alternative. You can embed reports directly into your code projects in .Net. In this case the report runs through the Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms and Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms namespaces, ReportViewer object. Each report will have a ".rdlc" extension instead of ".rdl", though the two files types are actually equivalent. There is an ASP.Net version of the ReportViewer that allows you to integrate these reports into your website. You just need to drag the ReportViewer control from the toolbox into your website to configure it. For more information, see the MSDN overview of [ReportViewer Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671(VS.80).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a whole license you can always use reportviewer.  Just so I dont put too much answer out here, the big site for this is gotreportviewer.com.

The reportviewer control does the work of the reporting services server when it comes to the generation of reports.  RDL files are like xml files and dont do much until they are interpreted.  If you embed the reportviewer in your application on the web the work will be done on the user side.  It is simialar to microsofts xps format, it has to be interpreted.

If you don't want to create an application for your reports the new version of sql2008 with advanced controls allows you to install a free version of reporting services.  It doesnt have all of the goodies but it works for simple deployments.